# Interpreting Strings as Other Data Types in Python

Tags: python, string, parsing, python-2.4

I'm reading a file into python 2.4 that's structured like this:

```
field1: 7
field2: "Hello, world!"
field3: 6.2
```

The idea is to parse it into a dictionary that takes `fieldfoo` as the key and whatever comes after the colon as the value.

I want to convert whatever is after the colon to it's "actual" data type, that is, `'7'` should be converted to an `int`, `"Hello, world!"` to a string, etc. The only data types that need to be parsed are ints, floats and strings.  Is there a function in the python standard library that would allow one to make this conversion easily?

The only things this should be used to parse were written by me, so (at least in this case) safety is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For older python versions, like the one being asked, the `eval` function can be used but, to **reduce** evilness, a `dict` to be the global namespace should be used as second argument to avoid function calls.

```
>>> [eval(i, {"__builtins__":None}) for i in ['6.2', '"Hello, world!"', '7']]
[6.2, 'Hello, world!', 7]
```

Comment: it raise "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing" when applying "alphanumeric" values instead to interpret a string.

Answer (score 6):

First parse your input into a list of pairs like `fieldN: some_string`.  You can do this easily with `re` module, or probably even simpler with slicing left and right of the index `line.strip().find(': ')`.  Then use a literal eval on the value `some_string`:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('6.2')
6.2
>>> type(_)
<type 'float'>
>>> ast.literal_eval('"Hello, world!"')
'Hello, world!'
>>> type(_)
<type 'str'>
>>> ast.literal_eval('7')
7
>>> type(_)
<type 'int'>
```

Comment: The version of python I'm using doesn't have the `ast` module.

Comment: @MikeSamuel obviously the input must be preprocessed into `fieldn: string` pairs first, but that part is trivial.  @julio.alegria `_` is a handy shortcut for the last returned value in the interactive interpreter.  @Dan ..erm.. now you tell me ;)  upgrade python? is there a reason why you need to use such an old version?

Comment: @Mike Samuel: Safety isn't an issue for me. I don't need to parse anything that I haven't written myself with another program. +1 on your comment for pointing it out, though.

Comment: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-September/1219992.html  here someone backported literal_eval to 2.4, but it all sounds a bit hacky to me.  i would prefer to upgrade python than use that, personally.

Comment: @wim: I figured out I could just use `eval()`. See answer below, and thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I know it's hacky and evil, but I don't see any other easy way of doing it.

Comment: @juliomalegria are you seriously that lost?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `yaml` to parse the literals which is better than `ast` in that it does not throw you an error if strings are not wrapped around extra pairs of apostrophes or quotation marks.

```py
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml.safe_load('7')
7
>>> yaml.safe_load('Hello')
'Hello'
>>> yaml.safe_load('7.5')
7.5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can attempt to convert it to an `int` first using the built-in function `int()`. If the string cannot be interpreted as an int a `ValueError` exception is raised. You can then attempt to convert to a `float` using `float()`. If this fails also then just return the initial string

```
def interpret(val):
    try:
        return int(val)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return float(val)
        except ValueError:
            return val
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the *"only data types that need to be parsed are `int`, `float` and `str`"*, maybe somthing like this will work for you:

```
entries = {'field1': '7', 'field2': "Hello, world!", 'field3': '6.2'}

for k,v in entries.items():
    if v.isdecimal():
        conv = int(v)
    else:
        try:
            conv = float(v)
        except ValueError:
            conv = v
    entries[k] = conv

print(entries)
# {'field2': 'Hello, world!', 'field3': 6.2, 'field1': 7}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [strconv](https://github.com/bruth/strconv) lib.

```
In [22]: import strconv
/home/tworec/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/strconv.py:200: UserWarning: python-dateutil is not installed. As of version 0.5, this will be a hard dependency of strconv fordatetime parsing. Without it, only a limited set of datetime formats are supported without timezones.
  warnings.warn('python-dateutil is not installed. As of version 0.5, '

In [23]: strconv.convert('1.2')
Out[23]: 1.2

In [24]: type(strconv.convert('1.2'))
Out[24]: float

In [25]: type(strconv.convert('12'))
Out[25]: int

In [26]: type(strconv.convert('true'))
Out[26]: bool

In [27]: type(strconv.convert('tRue'))
Out[27]: bool

In [28]: type(strconv.convert('12 Jan'))
Out[28]: str

In [29]: type(strconv.convert('12 Jan 2018'))
Out[29]: str

In [30]: type(strconv.convert('2018-01-01'))
Out[30]: datetime.date
```

Comment: Actually, it does not handle unicode strings, see https://github.com/bruth/strconv/issues/2

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps to do what you are trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

a = {'field1': 7}
b = {'field2': "Hello, world!"}
c = {'field3': 6.2}

temp1 = type(a['field1'])
temp2 = type(b['field2'])
temp3 = type(c['field3'])

print temp1
print temp2
print temp3
```

Comment: I don't want to get the types of objects in a dictionary, I want to convert strings in a dictionary that are annotated as python types to the types they represent.

Comment: Can you post example input and output, that will easier to understand?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [wim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9072884/789750) for helping me figure out what I needed to search for to figure this out.

One can just use `eval()`:

```
>>> a=eval("7")
>>> b=eval("3")
>>> a+b
10
>>> b=eval("7.2")
>>> a=eval("3.5")
>>> a+b
10.699999999999999
>>> a=eval('"Hello, "')
>>> b=eval('"world!"')
>>> a+b
'Hello, world!'
```

Comment: Great! Now make sure you don't import `os` in your source, to avoid evaluating values like `os.system("rm *")`. And that's not the only way. So this method works, but it's not recommended.

Comment: It's evil and insecure, but this entire script is a quick and dirty fix that should (ideally) be thrown away in a few months.

Comment: I had a Q&D awk script that I wrote in 1989 implementing a very crude commercial order processor “until the app we wait is ready” that was still being used up to 1996 that I know of, and a Q&D 1995 QBasic army service chores assigner (whatever you might understand of it :) that was still used in 2007 (albeit modified by others to no end, I presume), so I'm certain “quick&dirty” programs are as quick but lots more dirtier than people usually think they are.